# How can motion along a spiral curve conclude in a finite time, but have infinite turns around the origin?

Tags: kinematics, mathematical-physics, mathematics

The first question of the book "200 puzzling problems in physics" has 3 point objects forming a triangle(equal sides), and they start moving towards one another - A always moves towards B, B always moves towards C, C always moves towards A. If one solves it, we get a spiral curve for the motion of each point object - $$r = r_0 \cdot e^{-c~\theta} \tag 1$$. The problem is that the object reaches the center of the original triangle in a finite time, but the number of turns it takes around the origin is infinite. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the same way that it's possible for an infinite sum of terms to sum to a finite number:

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + ... = 1$.

Generally speaking, there's nothing contradictory about something happening an infinite number of times in a finite amount of time.  All that's needed is for the amount of time it takes for that thing to happen to decrease significantly each time.  In your example, the amount of time it takes one of the objects to do one turn around the origin gets smaller and smaller each time (or in other words, its angular speed approaches infinity in finite time, similar to how the function $1/(2 - x)$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches 2).

Comment: Thank you! You mean the angular speed approaches infinity, right? But yeah,

Comment: If the angular speed approaches infinity, the linear speed does too.  So yes, they both do.

Comment: But the linear speed is constant in the question. The radius is approaching zero, and angular speed is in a multiple of v/r, so I still think it's just the angular speed approaching infinity.

Comment: You're talking about the radial speed, the speed towards the center.  The linear speed is the speed in the direction of motion, and that speed will go to infinity.

Comment: Aren't both constant? With each turn, the length of the path in it approaches zero, and with speed(radial, linear, whatever remaining same), time gets smaller for each turn.

Comment: Hmm actually yes I believe you're right.  Or at least, it's possible it doesn't go to infinity.  I'll modify my answer to specify angular speed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you take the limit of above spiral equation of an object in polar coordinates, when $\theta \to \infty$ :
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} r_0 e^{-c \theta} = 0~~\text{for}~r_0 \in \mathbb R ∧ c>0 \tag 1,$$

you'll see that object can reach spiral center ($r=0$) solution, *if and only if* it makes infinite angle rotation around the center, i.e. $\theta = \infty$. Divide this per $2\pi$ and you will get number of turns needed to reach the center-
$$ n = \frac {\theta}{2\pi}= \frac {\infty}{2\pi}=\infty. \tag 2$$

Just pure math.

Comment: No, I knew that, I was just wondering how it's possible that a infinite number of turns take a finite time. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Well, to me your question a bit reassembles [Paradoxes_of_motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Paradoxes_of_motion)  which were analysed by ancient Greeks. For example "Achilles and the tortoise". Just that your "paradox" is "tuned" to angular motion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In your link there is the paradox of an object having to cover half of the distance left, so there will be infinite number of steps. But the time taken for these steps takes less and less and adds up to a finite time, just like in my question of angular motion.

Comment: As about constancy of angular speed, we can solve for $\theta$ : $$\theta = -\frac{1}{c}\ln{\frac {r}{r_0}}$$, then differentiating that wrt time we get angular speed : $$\dot{\theta}=\omega=-\frac{\dot{r}(t)}{c r(t)}$$. Now $\omega=\omega(\dot{r}(t), r(t))$, i.e. it depends on the behavior of radial speed and radius decreasing tendencies. So at this point is hard to say if $\omega = \text{const}$ or not.

Comment: w approaches infinity. Zeno's paradox has the length intervals decreasing and speed constant, my angular version of the paradox has the each turn the same constant which is 2pi, with speed approaching infinity. The result of both is time take approaches zero. Thanks for the initial answer and sorry for the late reply, I didn't see yours.